# Are all hash code algorithms of the same type calculated the same way?

Tags: hash, hashcode, sha256

I was just wondering if all SHA256 Hashes are calculated the same way. Like if I give the input to this lib like the following, how could I reproduce the same output with another SHA256 Hash algorithm?

```
lib1_gf_InitializeHashInput();
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(a);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(b);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(c);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(d);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(e);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(f);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(g);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(h);
lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput(i);
string HASHCODE = lib1_gf_GenerateSHA256HashCode();

void lib1_gf_AddIntegerToHashInput (int lp_integer) {
    lib1_gf_AddByteToHashInput(lp_integer);
    lib1_gf_AddByteToHashInput(lp_integer >> 8);
    lib1_gf_AddByteToHashInput(lp_integer >> 16);
    lib1_gf_AddByteToHashInput(lp_integer >> 24);
}

void lib1_gf_AddByteToHashInput (byte lp_byte) {
    HashInputData[HashInputSize] = lp_byte;
    HashInputSize += 1;
}
```

Here's the lib link (yes it is sha256 as well as md5): http://www.sc2mapster.com/assets/md5-hash/

Direct Download link: http://www.sc2mapster.com/media/files/541/355/Hash_lib.SC2Lib

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes -- except that's too short, thank you SO.  SHA256 is a specification for a particular algorithm that should always present the same results for the same input, no matter whose implementation you use.

Comment: So, if you took a look at the lib, how are the integers added? I Program in C#, not this language. I'll add the necessary methods to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

SHA256 algorithm is one.

So, yes, SHA256 hash is calculated always the same way.

Note that source code of SHA256 (and other SHA) hash generation algorithm is [here](http://www.aarongifford.com/computers/sha.html).